# Violin melody (Vicetone-Tremble)

Tags: design, sound

1:25
How can I get that amazing sound?
I mean, what software do I need? Nexus, Sylenth..?
Please I need help!
Thanks!

Comment: It's a violin....being a violin... I'm not sure what you are asking for.  If you can clarify this in to a workable question it can be re-opened.

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot that. I mean, what kind of software do I need? Nexus, Sylenth...

Comment: it still really is not clear what you are asking.  Are you looking for a software recommendation on what software to use to make something that sounds like that.  If so, it's way too broad as any audio software could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Buy some orchestral sound sampler and learn some basic music theory .....